# resize image, get rid of 0-valued pixels Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, resize

I've got an image with all pixel values set to 0 except for a small rectangular window region. What I'd like to do is resize the image to get rid of all the 0 valued pixels and just be left with the rectangular window region. What's the easiest way to do this in Matlab?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[r, c] = find(img);

img_cropped = img(min(r):max(r), min(c):max(c))
```